# How to filter backbone collection to show tags

Tags: backbone.js, filter, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm creating a bookmarking tool that lets you create a list of stored bookmarks from an in-page form. The list will include an identifier tag (eg - Amazon www.amazone.com tag: shopping). From this created list, I want to also have a list showing the various tags that have been named.

This should probably use the filter method, but I cannot seem to get it to filter a correct list; I keep getting each tag listed for each URL created so there are multiple examples of the same tag.

Here is the code that correctly works in creating my form, the resulting URL list, and the module exports. This is from my Views js file:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var listTemplate = require('../../templates/addresslist.hbs');
var formTemplate = require('../../templates/addressform.hbs');
var detailTemplate = require('../../templates/addressdetail.hbs');

var AddressFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'form',
  template: formTemplate,
  events: {
    'submit': 'addAddress'
  },
  render: function(){
    var renderedHtml = this.template();
    this.$el.html(renderedHtml);
    return this;
  },
  addAddress: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.collection.create({
      title: $('#title').val(),
      url: $('#url').val(),
      tag: $('#tag').val(),
    });
    $('#title').val('');
    $('#url').val('');
    $('#tag').val('');
  },
});

var AddressListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderItem);
  },
  render: function(){
    return this;
  },
  renderItem: function(address){
    console.log('address', address);
    var addressItem = new AddressItemView({model: address});
    this.$el.append(addressItem.render().el);
  }
});

var AddressItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  template: listTemplate,
  render: function(){
    var context = this.model.toJSON();
    this.$el.html(this.template(context));
    return this;
  }
});

var AddressDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: detailTemplate,
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html('').append(this.template);
    return this;
  }
});

module.exports = {
  'AddressFormView': AddressFormView,
  'AddressListView': AddressListView,
  'AddressItemView': AddressItemView,
  'AddressDetailView': AddressDetailView,
}
```

My router js file looks like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var views = require('./views/addressview');
var models = require('./models/address');

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'detail/:id/': 'detail'
  },

  initialize: function(){
    this.collection = new models.AddressCollection();
  },

  index: function(){
    var addressForm = new views.AddressFormView({collection: this.collection});
    $('.app').html(addressForm.render().el);

    var addressListing = new views.AddressListView({collection: this.collection});
    $('.app').append(addressListing.render().el);

    this.collection.fetch();
  },

  detail: function(addressId){
    this.collection.fetch().done(function(){
      var address = this.collection.get(addressId);
      var addressDetail = new views.AddressDetailView({model: address});
      $('.app').html(addressDetail.render().el);
    }.bind(this));
  },
});

var router = new Router();

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I don't see where any filtering is being done.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what exactly is your problem either. Maybe try rephrasing the question?

Comment: @TJ  Yes, I did not do a great job of posting this question. In short, I'm trying to understand how to use collection.filter method to pull out each unique tag. The code above does not contain my efforts to do that; it shows everything up to that point. Perhaps I'll delete this and repost a more concise request.

Comment: It'd be helpful to show us the format of your collection object. Also, there is a `uniq` method in underscore that takes an array and returns it unique.

Answer (score 0):

Create new event in view for multiple tag selection

```
tagSelected :function(event){
  var tags = [<tag1>,<tag2>] //getting from multiple tag selection
  var models = _.filter(this.collection.models,function(model){
     return tags.indexOf(model.get('tag')) >= 0;
  })
  this.collection.reset(models);
  this.render();
})
```